# Good practice for hiding primary keys from a client

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Later on in my client, I may fetch a RESTful endpoint like this:

```
GET /v1/users/1
```

The query to retrieve the users would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1;
```

I want to avoid the approaches above so I can hide primary keys from user-facing web apps.

I thought I could do something like this instead to solve that problem:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    _id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

The HTTP call now becomes something like this:

```
GET /v1/users/a129fjf24f0jwef94f
```

...and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE _id = a129fjf24f0jwef94f;
```

What are the downsides to such an implementation at the database level, if any, other than excess storage? I would also have to use the `_id` on queries where I involve joins of other tables, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the primary key? What has necessitated that?

Comment: This is a contrived example, but in some cases users should not know the quantity of items of a certain feature for competitiveness, and as it stands the quantity can be derived from the primary key ID.

Comment: *in some cases users should not know the quantity of items* Use randomly programmatically generated primary key (within possible values range) instead of autoincrement.

Comment: @Akina Well the thing is I still want an auto-increment to benefit from its features, I just don't want that visible to a user.

Comment: In any case you have programmatically-generated random-valued field. And what the difference it is primary key or simple unique field?

Comment: Yeah, updated question just now. It would just be a `UNIQUE`, not another primary key.

Comment: If you have used the InnoDB engine  just do not declare any primary key at all. Then engine will create the hidden unsigned bigint not null autoincremented column that will be used as PK and clustering key for all other keys declared explicitly. But if you want to incapsulate the database you should restrict the users by thoroughly crafted stored routines.

Comment: *Then engine will create the hidden unsigned bigint not null autoincremented column* RowID is 6-byte (unsigned) integer ([InnoDB - Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)) whereas BIGINT is 8-byte. And RowID is always created (check - removing primary index when no another indices do not increase .IBD file if it was "packed").

Comment: @McNets I am not publishing my schema, no user will ever see it. I'm speaking strictly from a user-interface point of view. If someone (a hacker) looks at the URL's, network requests, etc...then they will be able to derive information I don't want them to be able to from the primary key ID.

Comment: In `WHERE _id = a129fjf24f0jwef94f`, you need quotes around the string!

Comment: @RickJames Haha yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan A:

Your basic is probably good.

`_id` could be computed as `MD5(CONCAT('salt', id))`.  `'salt'` is some secret string; it's purpose is to make it harder for a hacker to discover your mapping between `id` and `_id`.

An `MD5` can be stored in `CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii` or, via `UNHEX(...)` in `BINARY(16)` -- 32 or 16 bytes, respectively.

Since that is 32 hex digits, you *may* have an issue with such a long string.  If so, then you could use some shorter 1-way hash, but that increases the risk of an accidental dup.  At that point, you would need to take advantage of the `UNIQUE` index, toss the `id`, and move on to the next.

Plan B:

Create a table with all the numbers from, say, 100,000 to 999,999.  This would give you 900K 6-digit numbers.  Sort them (`ORDER BY RAND()`) and add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id.  Now you have a mapping that is unique, and limited to 6 characters.  (Variants would involve hex or base64 or all letters.  But watch out for "4-letter words" buried in strings.)  (MariaDB has an easy way to build such a "sequence" table.)

Plan C:

When you need a new `_id`, compute `RIGHT(RAND(), 6)`, then verify that it is not a dup.  (A simple Stored Function can do that task.)  (Caution: When you get close to a million, the function will bog down due to dups.)  `6` limits you to 1M numbers; increase the `6` to get more.

Minor bug:  It is possible to get a decimal point; any of these would be safer:

```
REPLACE(RIGHT(RAND(), 6), '.', '')
FLOOR(1000000*RAND())
100000 + FLOOR(900000*RAND())  -- always 6 digits long
```

Comment: I was thinking to just generate the random string in my code and store it to the database.

Comment: @Lansana - random string in your code -- Sure.

Comment: What type would you recommend for this column? CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY? What size? Why? Thanks!

Comment: @Lansana - How about `CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  You could put letters and numbers, with a limit of over a million.  Consider the issue of case folding.  If `a=A`, then `COLLATE ascii_general_ci`, if `a<>A`, then `COLLATE ascii_bin`.  6 bytes is big enough for lots of users, but small enough to not be a burden the database.  Adjust if needed.